# Intersection of line and lattice points

Tags: coordinate-systems, integer-lattices

Consider the Cartesian plane.

A line originates from origin. How many lattice points would it cross?

A lattice pointis a point with both coordinates integers.

My attempt:

Let the line be $y=mx$ since it passes through origin

For $x$ and $y$ to be both integers $m$ must be rational but we can also choose an irrational value of $m$ and hence a line need not pass through any lattice point exept origin

But in practice (on graph paper) it seems to always pass through a lattice point

What is the flaw here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In practice" your line does not have zero width. Since a line with irrational slope comes as close as you wish to many lattice points the fuzziness of the pencil lead (or the pixel width on a screen) will show the line (almost) passing through lattice points.

Comment: So the only problem is the accuracy of real measurements?

Comment: Yes. Real measurements always produce rational values with some error you try to control. The number line with its irrational numbers is an abstract mathematical construct, not something you experience in the "real world".

Answer (score 1):

"In practice" your line does not have zero width. Since a line with irrational slope comes as close as you wish to many lattice points the fuzziness of the pencil lead (or the pixel width on a screen) will show the line (almost) passing through lattice points.

Hence your reasonung is correct